# Php include Parent/Parent/Parent

Tags: php, directory, include, parent

So i need to include a config File from 3 Directories above.
File Structure: root/template/default/premium/myFile.php
I am trying to include: root/include/config.php

My attempts:

```
if(include('../../../include/config.php') == true){
    echo "Config loaded succesfully<br>";
}else{
    echo "There was a Big Time Error loading the Config!<br>";
}
```

This one is not working, I keep getting the Big Time Error Message ;)

Next i tried with:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/config.php');
```

Also no Luck with this one if I try to access my defines it´s not working.

After  Dormilich suggestion on checking the manual i found a Mistake and changed
my Code as followed:

```
if((include'../../../include/config.php') == true){
        echo "Config loaded succesfully<br>";
    }else{
        echo "There was a Big Time Error loading the Config!<br>";
    }
```

Still not working

Comment: For your second try you must add `/` .... `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/config.php');`

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-125 for the explanation why it doesn't work.

Comment: I see. But its still not working...

Comment: So. If the correct code: `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/config.php');`  don't work .... You have not your `include` folder in the server document_root. Check first: `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and manually compare with the the real path of `/include/config.php`

Comment: @MTK You are right i´ve made a Mistake but i dont know where. I was on this for 2 Hours and after writing the same include again it works!

Comment: I like using `__DIR__` and going from there. `DOCUMENT_ROOT` was never that reliable with our slaphappy IT guys.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I will try that out too!

Answer (score 0):

```
if((include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/config.php') == true)
{
    echo "Config loaded succesfully<br>";
}
else
{
    echo "There was a Big Time Error loading the Config!<br>";
}
```

This did the Trick for me. I think i may just mispelled somewhere.
But still thanks for bringing the Attention again to the manual.